# Redmine IMAP connection slow on Server 2003

Tags: imap, exchange-server, redmine

Redmine 2.1.2 using a Thin service on Windows Server 2003

Great product, finally have it working after a few days of tinkering. The last stumbling block is the 'receive_imap'. I'm running manually from the command line and it seems to work (emails are being received and added to tickets) but the command never ends.

The ruby.exe process is still in task manager but never ends no matter how long I wait. If I kill the ruby.exe then the command line goes back to 'Terminate Batch Job Y/n'.

Command is:

```
rake -f D:\Redmine\Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail username=user@server.com.au password=password
```

Adding '--trace' to the end shows nothing interesting, just gets to '**Execute redmine:email:receive_imap'.

Strange though that it does succeed in bringing the emails in!

I left the process running over the weekend and it seems to have ended at some point. I pushed enter at the command line and it went back to the prompt.

It seems that the process will end after about 30 minutes if I let it go.

When I run the rake command, within about 15 seconds the mailbox is checked and updates to the issues are logged, but after that the process is just sitting there doing nothing.

Is there any additional logging I can enable to see what the issue is? The production.log doesn't show much and the mail server just sees the connect etc.

Watching the IMAP connections in Exchange System Manager the actual IMAP connection is still connected for the entire time the process is going.

UPDATE:

I've just set up a Bitnami stack in a VM and ran the same command, it runs in seconds and the emails are imported straight away... so it's def not an Exchange issue. I'm struggling to see what the difference could be!

I can telnet to the mail server on port 143 so it's not the firewall. I've also installed the 1.8.7 version of Ruby and used 'pik' to switch to it before running the rake command and still the same issue.

I'm really struggling here as this is the only feature stopping us from going live now!

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Details:

ruby -v:

```
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12) [i386-mingw32]
```

Rails -v:

```
Rails 3.2.8

gem list:
actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.2.1)
coderay (1.0.8)
daemons (1.1.9)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0.rc.4 x86-mingw32)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.7.5, 1.5.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.11)
tzinfo (0.3.34, 0.3.33)
ya2yaml (0.31)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of you.
My solution isn’t the ideal, but works.
I added the command above at the end of method check on the file apps\redmine\htdocs\lib\redmine\imap.rb:

```
Process.exit!(true)
```

I have helped.